# Using Google API Refresh Token in Python

Tags: python, google-api, refresh-token, facesservlet

I made a personal use app that just queries my gmail for a certain type of email. The app is successfully running on a pi night and day making requests to the Gmail service every thirty seconds.

However every week or so I get this error:

```
messages = gmail.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute() # 
q='is:unread'
File "C:\Users\rexma\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\rexma\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 839, in execute
method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
File "C:\Users\rexma\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 166, in _retry_request
resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\rexma\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 186, in new_request
credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
File "C:\Users\rexma\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 761, in _refresh
self._do_refresh_request(http)
File "C:\Users\rexma\Anaconda3\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 819, in _do_refresh_request
raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Token has 
been expired or revoked.
```

Which forces me to go back in, delete my old credentials and rerun the authorization. I've tried to do the other fixes online like setting

`flow.authorization_url(access_type = 'offline', approval_prompt='force')`

But the 'OAuth2WebServerFlow' object has no attribute 'authorization_url'.

Here is my full authorization code:

```
def authenticate(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, APPLICATION_NAME, SCOPE, credential_name):
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')

if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
    os.makedirs(credential_dir)

credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, credential_name)

store = Storage(credential_path)
credentials = store.get()

if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPE)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    # flow.authorization_url(access_type='offline', approval_prompt='force')
    credentials = run_flow(flow, store)

return credentials
```

I'm definitely still a scrub with OAuth2, even having read [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). I just want to know how I can have my app use the refresh token in the json credentials to keep running without expiring.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i am also facing the same